# Navbar width setting on max-width 480px

Tags: css

Navigation bar with a logo, a paragraph, and three font-awesome icons not covering the whole width in a max-width of 480px.

Have added display flex property, made the flex direction to be row, and the margins to be Zero but still not working for me.

```
    @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0.1em;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

I am expecting the items in the navbar to cover the whole width, without leaving a blank margin on the right.

Comment: What margins? Please add link to page. This code is okay.

Comment: Can you share the html code of your navbar?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the rest of your code for the navbar. I suspect if you add a background color in there you’ll see it’s fine, and that the problem is your elements within.

Comment: HTML         <nav class="navbar">
 <div class="navbar-logo-onphone">
 <img src="logo.png" alt="smart-biz logo" />
 </div>  <div class="navbar-p-onphone"> <p>The best<br> online sellers</p>
</div>  <div class="cart-btn-onphone"> <span class="nav-icon-cart">
  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i> </span>
  <div class="cart-items-onphone">0</div></div>
 <div class="phone-icons"> <span class="nav-icon-search-onphone">
   <i class="fas fa-search"></i> </span> </span>
        <span class="nav-icon-onphone">
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </nav>

Comment: CSS @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { .navbar { background-color: rgb(146, 145, 145); max-width: 480px; height: 70px;margin: 0; display: flex; padding: 0.1em; align-items: center; position: relative;transform: translate(-50% 50%);} .nav-icon-onphone {margin-left: 10%;}.cart-btn-onphone {position: relative;cursor: pointer; margin-left: 0.5%; } navbar-p-onphone {color: green; font-weight: bold; max-width: 25%; height: auto; text-align: center; margin-left: 1%; font-size: 80%;} .navbar-logo-onphone img {max-width: 10rem; height: 12rem;}
  .nav-icon-cart { font-size: 1.5rem; }

Comment: That's all the code I have for the HTML and CSS code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of issues in your code. The icons on the right are stacking one onto other, not sure if it is desired.
If not then add a parent `div` to all those icons and put them in the flexbox. This will stack them in a row.
Regarding navbar to cover the whole width, I think you should go with `justify-content: space-between` to your class `navbar`

```css
.navbar {
    background-color: rgb(146, 145, 145);
    max-width: 480px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0.1em;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;  /*added line*/
}
/* added code for parent div class*/
.icons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-logo-onphone"> <img src="logo.png" alt="smart-biz logo" /> </div>
    <div class="navbar-p-onphone">
        <p>The best<br> online sellers</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icons"> <!-- added parent div -->
        <div> <span class="nav-icon-cart"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i> </span>
            <div class="cart-items-onphone">0</div>
        </div>
        <div> <span class="nav-icon-search-onphone"> <i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="nav-icon-onphone"> <i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much @AdityaSrivast, it has worked well for me, Cheers